# Spring WS Client using JAXB Marshaller

Tags: spring, jaxb, spring-ws, webservicetemplate

Is there a way i can refer to a XSD in my Spring WS Client project and not generate the POJO's from the XSD and still be able to refer the JAXB Objects, build request and call a webservice using WebServiceTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use JAXB objects but you don't want to generate JAXB objects. If that is the case, then the answer is no.

You can still use Spring-WS at the client side to send a SOAP-request which is not generated by marshalling objects. Check out the [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html) for examples and more information.